# Increment a title in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make the title  increment by number in the form below as the user adds a level (a new form).   For example when the user clicks add level it should say "Level 2" and if they add another one it says "Level 3"

Here is the second partial in which the title I would like to increment

```
<fieldset class="levelCreator">
<%= f.label :title, "Level"%> <br /><%# This is what I would like to increment %>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br />
<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
<%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "btn btn-danger btn-mini remove_fields" %>
<%= f.fields_for :steps do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'step_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "add step", f, :steps %>
```

here is the first partial in which the add level button exists

```
    <%= form_for(@course) do |f|  %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages_courses' %>

        <div class="courseCreator">

        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>

        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_field :description %>

        <%= f.label :typeof %>
        <%= f.text_field :typeof %>

        </div>

        <%= f.fields_for :levels do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'level_fields', f: builder %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_fields "add level", f, :levels %>


        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary save" %>

    <% end %>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `> "Level 2".next
 => "Level 3"`

Comment: Did not work.  thank you though

Comment: `"Level".next` won't increment to `"Level 1"`. You have to start with a number as the last character in the string or the trick doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be very elegant, but a counter in the parent view should do it:

view:

```
<% index = 1 %>
<%= f.fields_for :levels do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'level_fields', {f: builder, index: index} %>
  <% index = index + 1 %>
<% end %>
```

partial:

```
<%= f.label :title, "Level #{index}"%>
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but it just outputs "Level 1" after I copied and pasted your code.  It does not increment for some reason.

Comment: Came back to this and I needed an @ sign for whatever reason